# How many shrouds do I get?

Tags: dnd-4e, assassin

was just wondering with playing my assassin. I normally get to put up to a maximum of 4 shrouds on a target. If I take the feat Crimson Eye Action which says When you spend an action point, you also subject your target to an additional shroud. Does that mean I can have up to 5 shrouds on a target?

Comment: Hi Tony! It looks like you've created a new account for each question you've asked. You can use the `flag` link to flag this for Moderator attention and leave them a note to merge your accounts. :) Then you'd have enough rep to do more stuff around here!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that these feats let you exceed the maximum limit of 4 shrouds on a target, but rather let you pile on shrouds more quickly. Due to [Assassin's Shroud](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=9400)<sup>[DDI]</sup> limit of *once per round* you'd usually need 4 rounds to get to the maximum number of shrouds but with the feat you can do it in 3 rounds.

Iirc there are three feats that do something like this:

- [Crimson Eye Action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1790)<sup>[DDI]</sup>
- [Killer's Insight](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1798)<sup>[DDI]</sup>
- [Velvet Blade Trick](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1808)<sup>[DDI]</sup>

Comment: There's also Grave Dust Advantage, Keeper of the Black Flame, and Insidious Shroud.

Comment: Also, some powers that let you use Assassin's Shroud more than once per turn:  Targeted for Death, Shadow Link, Withering Onslaught, Grasp of the Obsidian Tomb, Soul of Death, Killer's Judgment, and Doom Foretold.